taylor polynomial of a harmonic function is harmonic
Let $u \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a harmonic function and $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that the Taylor polynomial
$$
T_m(x) = \sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n, |\alpha| \leq m} \frac{\partial^\alpha u(0)}{\alpha!} x^\alpha 
$$
of $u$ of order $m$ at zero is well-defined and harmonic.
Details:

$\alpha$ is a multi-index, i.e., $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{N}$.
$|\alpha| = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \cdots + \alpha_n$.
$\partial^\alpha u = \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|} u}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1} \partial x_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots \partial x_n^{\alpha_n}}$.
$x^\alpha = x_1^{\alpha_1} x_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$.
$\alpha! = \alpha_1! \alpha_2! \cdots \alpha_n!$.

How can we prove that $T_m(x)$ is harmonic and well-defined?

What have you tried?

@BrunoB $
\Delta x^\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2} x^\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i (\alpha_i - 1) x^{\alpha - 2e_i}
$

This is only an idea, I'm not fully certain if it will work out, but what you could do is show that the remainder from Taylor's theorem is harmonic, potentially?

@BrunoB Thank you, but I don't see how it should work out sadly
